# Jquery parse xml

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have a xml variable like

```
var xmlData="<evn:soap><con:firstname>ravindra</con:firstname></evn:soap>";
```

Now I would like to parse this

I have done

```
 alert($(xmlData).find('firstname').text());
```

But not able to get output. even also try like

```
alert($(xmlData).find('con:firstname').text());
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The `:` makes jQuery think `firstname` is a custom selector.  You need to escape it with a double backslash (`\\`) to tell jQuery that it is part of the tag name:

```
alert($(xmlData).find('con\\:firstname').text());
```